# Can't install gdown on kaggle

Tags: python, google-drive-api, artificial-intelligence, kaggle

I am using the following command to link my google drive to kaggle

```
! conda install -y gdown
```

but I get this error

`CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/rapidsai/linux-64/current_repodata.json>`

I tried pip install gdown but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your internet connection and then try again or if you have PyCharm you can install it directly by selecting the package you want to install .

Comment: No I specifically want to use kaggle

Comment: you could go to their website and can directly install the dataset

Comment: I want to use kaggle to access their GPU

Answer (score 0):

Same question, I open the "Internet" of kaggle which is on the right side of the ui just as the picture below:

[Internet of kaggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXuDZ.png)

Then I rerun the command, and solve the problem.

```
pip install gdown
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34693409)